# Android How do i get background application to front

Tags: android

How do i get a background app to front over my current app

for example

my application  << forground
watzapp         <<  background

how do i get watzapp in front ?

```
private ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.restartPackage("com.whatsapp");
```

i have searched but currently non was working anybody can share working code i will add to button click please.

I have a rooted device and i have been searching to kill or force stop other background apps non are working so i have come up with an idea that might work which is

call victim app to front find pid then kill it then go back into your app again.

on button click
set 10 second delay
call victim app to front
kill app by pid
when timer reaches 0 then your app pops in front

i have seen that when  app is in forground you are able to get pid for that app.
is this possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch an application from another application on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

Comment: use service for this

Answer (score 1):

You can start the main activity of the background application like launcher.if you do not know the name of activity,you can do like this:

```
    Intent launchIntent =  getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
    startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Comment: simon can you check my edited code and tell me if this is worth doing ?  i tested it , it kills the other apps but when i press home the apps i killed become black but not cleared from the home screen

Comment: If you only want to let the background application to be in front,    this is enough:            startActivity(launchIntent)  ,kill the process is not a good practice,because package manager still contain this reference of the killed process,so you can see it become black when you press home.And killing process is not equal to uninstalling package,it is still in home page if you killed this process.If you want to delete it in home page,you should uninstall that package in silent mode.hope it can help you.